# How can I get a binary from a .py file

Tags: linux, python, compiler

I need a program to compile python source code; as I found out at first I need to make a binary file from my python script.

I've already checked a lot of links, but still I haven't found something for Linux.

I found `py2bin` for OS/X, but there are no versions for Linux.

Comment: Python 2 or Python 3? Also, is [Nuitka](http://nuitka.net/) or [dis](https://docs.python.org/2/library/dis.html) closer to what you want?

Comment: Cython is a popular optimizing static compiler for Python.

Comment: https://wiki.python.org/moin/Freeze That method will compile executables for *nix systems. Although I'm not sure if that's what you want.

Comment: disassembling python code?

Comment: Unless you mean create "precompiled" python modules (`.pyc`)?

Comment: @xenoid from the title and context, I think it is just a typo. I fixed the question.

Comment: Check this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/40057634/175169 'cython'

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In my opinion your problem in Google stems for calling a compiler capable of producing binaries from python a "disassembler".

I have not found a true compiler, however I have found in Google a python <strike>compiler</strike> packager, which packs all the necessary files in a directory, obfuscating them, with an executable frontend: pyinstaller at http://www.pyinstaller.org/ ; it appears to be actively supported, as the last version 3.4 which was released on 2018-09-09, contrary to [py2bin](https://sourceforge.net/projects/py2bin/) which seems to be not actively maintained.

> Features:
>
> - Packaging of Python programs into standard executables, that work on
>     computers without Python installed.
> - Multi-platform, works under:
>     Windows (32-bit and 64-bit),
>     Linux (32-bit and 64-bit),
>     Mac OS X
>     (32-bit and 64-bit),
>     contributed suppport for FreeBSD, Solaris, HPUX,
>     and AIX.
> - Multi-version:
>     supports Python 2.7 and Python 3.3—3.6.

To install:

> ```
> pip install pyinstaller
> ```
>
> Then, go to your program’s directory and run:
>
> ```
> pyinstaller yourprogram.py
> ```
>
> This will generate the bundle in a subdirectory called dist.

Comment: pyinstaller doesn't compile python programs, it just pack so that the result package can be used like a binary package. So practically an extractor and execution of normal python. (it use pyc, so simple reverse engineering is difficult, but a tools that change identifier should also be used, if reverse engineering is to avoid).

Comment: @GiacomoCatenazzi Thanks, I already suspected that. I also suspect it to be the case of `py2bin`, you can place scripts/python/perl programs under a "binary" package in MacOS.

Comment: I doesn't know. On older time, there where a python to C (+compiler) (py2bin is so old, so maybe...). Cython could be a solution, but I doesn't know if and how the code should be modified (so it will be no more pure Python).

Comment: @GiacomoCatenazzi Thanks for your insights.

Comment: The referenced site is no more

Comment: @FractalSpace thanks will monitor this. In the meanwhile, there is a page at https://pyinstaller.readthedocs.io/en/stable/

Comment: @Rui, yes, that one worked

Answer (score 5):

Try [Nuitka](http://nuitka.net/). It takes a `.py` and then creates a `.bin`.
It works on Gnu+Linux and is in most popular distribution's software repositories.

> Nuitka is a Python compiler written in Python.
>
> It's fully compatible with Python 2.6, 2.7, 3.3, 3.4, 3.5, 3.6, and 3.7.
>
> You feed it your Python app, it does a lot of clever things, and spits out an executable or extension module.
>
> Free license (Apache).

https://nuitka.net/pages/overview.html

Comment: Nuitka is Extremely Extremely slow. Slow beyond practical use.